# changing user model won't let me pull from Users now

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I have 1 database linking to 2 apps. For the second app, I change the Auth table like so...

```
$this->Auth->userModel = 'newAuthTable';
```

The only problem now is that I still want to run queries against my User model for the users table but it's pulling from 'newAuthTable' when I call `$users = $this->User->find('all');`

How can I run a query on the User model still?

Thank you.

Comment: you call that find('all') in users controller, right?

Comment: yes, I am calling this from the users controller. Should I call it from a different one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user is authenticated, change it back:

```
$this->Auth->userModel = 'users';
```